# command not found in linux shell and syntax error for then while using if else

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
#!/bin/bash
read n
sd=0
rev=0

if[[ $n -lt 0 ]];
then
echo "Not a positive number"
else
while [[ $n -gt 0 ]]
do
sd=$(( $n % 10 ))
rev=`expr $rev \* 10 + $sd`
n=$(( $n /10 ))
done

echo $rev
```

./scriptprog4.sh: line 6: if[[ 123 -lt 0 ]]: command not found
./scriptprog4.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./scriptprog4.sh: line 7:`then'

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Answer (score 1):

There was a missing `fi` statement (highly recommended to indent the code). Here's a working script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read n
sd=0
rev=0

if [[ $n -lt 0 ]]
then
    echo "Not a positive number"
else
    while [[ $n -gt 0 ]]
    do
        sd=$(( $n % 10 ))
        rev=`expr $rev \* 10 + $sd`
        n=$(( $n /10 ))
    done
fi

echo $rev
```

and an execution:

```
$ ./scriptprog4.sh 
123
321
```

Comment: Note that `expr` is not good practice. It's a holdout from the 1970s; any shell compatible with the 1992 POSIX sh specification supports `rev=$(( rev * 10 + sd ))`, which is both guaranteed to be available on any standard-compliant shell (`expr` is not), and more efficient (being built into the shell itself, as opposed to an external process).

Answer (score 0):

> ./scriptprog4.sh: line 6: if[[ 123 -lt 0 ]]: command not found

is caused by a missing space between `if` and `[[` both are reserved words in bash and must be separated by space

```
if [[ $n -lt 0 ]]; then
```